# Hide iSCSI targets in linux?

Tags: linux, iscsi, storage-area-network

My SAN reports the same targets with multiple IP addresses. Is there a way to hide some of those IPs so I don't see the same targets multiple times?

Comment: pipe it through grep?

Comment: or perhaps uniq

Comment: What are you using SCST,LIO or anything else? you can put allowed_portal attribute which will restrict target to specific IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bind iscsi targets to specific IP addresses and isolate that way. This is commonly known as target portal groups. Of course you can always use vlans to expose only desired vlans to your iscsi initiators. Combination of TPGs and vlans are most commonly the way target exposure is limited.

Answer (score 0):

If targets are presented through different networks this might be because you want to provide some redundancy. MPATHD can be used to map them to a single target. You just have to change the command mpathd uses to identify the drives a little bit (i.e. use the iSCSI-name without IP to identify the lun).